# Ignore Authentication Validation for static files in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-identity, identity

I use asp.net identity 2 in my application for implement Identity system.
When I Profile my application with **EF Profiler**.

I see some problem that it is connected to the database in per static file request. this is so bad for performance and page loading speed.
[image]

for solving this problem I write following code:

**Global.asax**

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (shouldIgnoreRequest())
            return;
        if (Context.User == null)
            return;
    }
    private bool shouldIgnoreRequest()
    {
        string[] reservedPath =
        {
            "/__browserLink",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/img",
            "/css"
            ,"/w",
            "/js"
        };
        var rawUrl = Context.Request.RawUrl;
        if (reservedPath.Any(path => rawUrl.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return BundleTable.Bundles.Select(bundle => bundle.Path.TrimStart('~'))
            .Any(bundlePath => rawUrl.StartsWith(bundlePath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("img/{*pathinfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("js/{*pathinfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("css/{*pathinfo}");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.gif");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.jpg");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.png");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.pdf");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.htm");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.swf");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.txt");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.xml");
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

How Can I Ignore this requests for authentication?

Comment: Show us your Identity configuration? I suspect your security stamp invalidator is set to invalidate the cookie on every request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try customizing the OnValidateIdentity to ignore unwanted requests:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   // ...
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = context =>
        {
            if(shouldIgnoreRequest(context)) // How to ignore Authentication Validations for static files in ASP.NET Identity
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
            return container.GetInstance<IApplicationUserManager>().OnValidateIdentity().Invoke(context);
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Using this method

```
private static bool shouldIgnoreRequest(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
{
    string[] reservedPath =
    {
        "/__browserLink",
        "/img",
        "/fonts",
        "/Scripts",
        "/Content",
        "/Uploads",
        "/Images"
    };
    return reservedPath.Any(path => context.OwinContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
                       BundleTable.Bundles.Select(bundle => bundle.Path.TrimStart('~')).Any(bundlePath => context.OwinContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(bundlePath,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```